# Programatically updating layout of a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to update layout of a fragment dynamically. I already have a xml layout file. After inflating it i update the layout.when i run the app it does a transition. From xml layout to programatically changed one. Why this transition occurs and how to overcome this. I have searched a lot but unable to solve this.

I am inflating layout in a fragment's onCreateView method.And updating using
ApplicationUIUtils.setUpUIForCurrentView(rootView, getContext());

here is the code :

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (rootView == null) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.specific_current_details,
                container, false);
        init();
        ApplicationUIUtils.setUpUIForCurrentView(rootView, getContext());
        rootView.invalidate();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Unsure of what this do: `ApplicationUIUtils.setUpUIForCurrentView(rootView, getContext());`

Comment: I did not undertand your question. What you want to do? Update the views content or the transiction? You placed your fragment statically in the activity xml?

Comment: I want to re-position all the views according to various device without any transition.

Answer (score 1):

What is **init()** ?

Why is this necessary for you?

```
ApplicationUIUtils.setUpUIForCurrentView(rootView, getContext());
rootView.invalidate();
```

When a fragment is being created, **onCreateView(...)** will generate the view of the fragment and update it.

If you want to add more view's objects, you can do within onCreateView(...). To create different views for different devices, you have to create different flows that modify the returning rootview.

Read this: [Supporting Different Devices](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html)

Comment: was this an answer or what?

Answer (score 0):

Without finding a satisfactory answer I just make all the views visibility="gone" in xml and then re-positioning in code making setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); Which at least remove transition issue but taking same time as before for loading.